# How to make a scope available to multiple models DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

If I want to make the following scopes available to multiple models how do I do so without having to add them directly into each model?

```
    scope :today, -> { where("DATE(created_at) = DATE(?)", Date.today ) }
    scope :yesterday, -> { where("DATE(created_at) = DATE(?)", 1.day.ago) }
    scope :last_week, -> { where("DATE(created_at) = DATE(?)", 1.week.ago) }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the prescribed ways is by using [concerns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).

You should be able to create a file like this at `app/models/concerns/dateable.rb`:

```
module Dateable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :today, -> { where("DATE(created_at) = DATE(?)", Date.today ) }
    scope :yesterday, -> { where("DATE(created_at) = DATE(?)", 1.day.ago) }
    scope :last_week, -> { where("DATE(created_at) = DATE(?)", 1.week.ago) }
  end
end
```

Then `include` it into the models that need it.

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  include Dateable
end

class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  include Dateable
end
```

Comment: So the dateable model will not have any columns or store any data, it is just used to house concerns and/or modules??

Comment: It's not actually a model. It's a module that gets included into 1 or more models. You can do this with controllers too.